# Is $k\vec{v}=\vec{v}k$ true in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is $k\vec{v}=\vec{v}k$ true in a vector space?

I may be a bit confused on this.  Doesn't seem to follow from the typical axioms.  Also can anyone comment on right/left distributive laws, as it seems the axioms don't include both.

Comment: Right scalar multinational is not defined in the usual definition of vector space

Comment: Did you *mean* to say multinational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, [the axioms presented for vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) are the axioms of a [left $R$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) where $R$ is a ring in general. Vector spaces are simply the special case where $R$ is a field. As Holo stated, with this definition, scalar multiplication is an operation $R\times V\to V$ and so $\vec v c$ is not defined. In the case where $R$ is commutative (which it is if it is a field), we can define a *right* $R$-module structure given a left $R$-module structure via $\vec v c \stackrel{\tiny def}{=}c\vec v$. Commutativity guarantees that this is well-behaved in general. This definition makes $V$ into an [$R$-$R$-bimodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition).

The "law" you're looking for is simply the *definition* of the right scalar multiplication.